# Rails: Use cocoon gem without asset pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline, redmine, redmine-plugins

I'm writing a plugin in Rails for Redmine, an application that does not support the asset pipeline. Is there any way I can use the cocoon gem, but without using the asset pipeline? My Rails version is 3.2.21

Doing the following:

```
//= require cocoon
```

does not work, because, again, I can't use asset pipeline.

Are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

You can make nested forms without the cocoon gem;

Let's say you have an invoice form where you want to include nested forms for customers and product.. **you can do this;**

```
<%= form_for @invoice do |f| %>

 <%= f.text_field :invoice_number %>

 <%= f.fields_for :customer do |c| %> // start nested form
  <%= c.label 'customer name' %>
  <%= c.text_field :customer_name %>
 <% end %>

 <%= f.fields_for :products do |p| %> // start nested form 
  <%= p.label 'product name' %>
  <%= p.label :product_name %>
 <% end %>

<%= f.submit 'save invoice', invoices_path, class: 'btn btn-primary' %>

<% end %>
```

**In your invoice model do:**

```
  has_one :customer
  has_many :products

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :customer, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :products, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
```

**Customer model**

```
  belongs_to :invoice
```

**Products model**

```
  belongs_to :invoice
```

**In your controller:**

```
def invoice_params
  params.require(:invoice).permit(:number customer_attributes: [:id, :customer_name :_destroy],  products_attributes: [:id, :product_name])
end
```

I used invoice as an explanation but you can change it with whatever models/relationships you have. But remember to follow the same pluralization terms. For example if you have `has_many :customers` in your model instead of `has_one :customer` remember to change accepts nested attributes to `accepts_nested_attributes_for :customers` and in your controller change `customer_attributes: [:id, :customer_name :_destroy]` to `customers_attributes: [:id, :customer_name :_destroy]`

And last but not least remember to change your f.fields_for also to whatever is in your model in this example case it would become: `<%= f.fields_for :customers do |c| %>`

**EDIT:**
In some cases you have to create the instances in your controller. In your new action of your controller you would have to do something like:

```
  def index
    @invoices = Invoice.all
  end


  # GET /invoices/new
  def new
    @invoice = Invoice.new
    @invoice.products.build
    @invoice.build_customer

  end
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Though the reason I wanted cocoon was so I could dynamically add and remove fields from my form (leveraging the link_to_add_association and link_to_remove_association)....I see no trivial way to do that without cocoon...

Comment: You can use jQuery to do that, it's quite easy and besides it's easier to adjust your own code instead of someone elses, plus you learn more from it. If you want i can teach you how to do it in jQuery.